# how to deploy vue js project to a subdirectory with vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, deployment

I want to deploy my Vue.js project to a sub directory let say abc.com/sub-directory using vue.config.js
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same URL for both production and staging servers.

```
let publicPath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/sub-directory' : '/sub-directory';
```

if you have different URLs for production and staging environments

```
let publicPath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/' : '/sub-directory';
```

You can read more about the build modes and deployment here.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply , should i create the sub directory folder on server , or should it create automatically

Comment: I think you will need to create it yourself.